# How to add reference to System.IdentityModel in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In VS 2015 RC I start a new project using the ASP.NET 5 Preview Template named "Web Site" and "No authentication".

I need to incorporate an existing helper class I have which references Microsoft.IdentityModel.

I run `Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel` but get an error as follows.

> Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel -Verbose Install failed.
>   Rolling back... Uninstalling NuGet package
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.6.1.7600.16394. Install-Package : An error
>   occurred while sending the request.At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel -Verbose
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Something similar happens if I use the package manager UI.

I tried instead adding a reference directly in frameworks > dnx451 in project.json but that yields a yellow triangle in the references section of solution explorer.

Anything obvious I'm doing wrong? Is there any other way I could try adding this reference?

Answer (score 0):

This was addressed by referencing it in the *dependencies* section of project.json.

```
{
  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4",
    ...
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel": "6.1.7600.16394"
  },
```